# In Haskell, how would I return a curried function that has a recursive definition?

Tags: haskell, currying

I am trying to achieve the following (defined in Javascript) in Haskell:
JS:

```
const fold = (c, h) => {
  const f = (n) => {
    return n === 0 ? c : h (f(n-1))
  }
  return f
}

fold(1, (x)=>x*10)(3)
```

Repl Link: https://repl.it/repls/ExperiencedTeemingLorikeet

I tried something along these lines (but does not work):

```
foldn c h =
 f  = f' n
      where f' 0 = c
            f' n =  h(f'(n-1))
 f
```

Essentially I am trying to create a named curried function "f" that can be returned. Also note that the definition of "f" is *recursive*
How can I do this in Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, all functions in Haskell are curried by default, so you can just do

```
fold c h n = if n == 0 then c else h (fold c h (n-1))
```

If you still prefer to have an `f` inside, then

```
fold c h = f
    where
        f 0 = c
        f n = h (f (n-1))
```

These versions are equivalent, and can be called like

```
fold 1 (*10) 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  Just declare a function that closes over `c` and `h`.

```
foldn c h = f where
  f 0 = c
  f n =  h . f $ n-1
```